# It seems like I cannot use MS leak detector for the new expression `new (std::nothrow)`. Is that correct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leak-detector, crtdbg.h

I'm trying to get the file and the line where the leak is occurring with the new expression `new (std::nothrow)`.

The commented new expression in the code below does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    int* p = new (_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) int(10);
//  int* q = new (std::nothrow, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) int(10); 
    #else
    int* p = new int(10);
    int* q = new int(10);
    #endif

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

I'm also curious to know where does `<iostream>` includes `<crtdbg.h>`. I just couldn't find it. But of course, it must be there, somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. Microsoft doesn't provide an `void* operator new(std::nothrow_t, const char* file, int line)` but you can trivially do so yourself. Just forward to the throwing version and in the `catch` handler `return NULL;`.

Comment: That seems to be answer. I understand this is a small detail, but do you know, by any chance, where the `<crtdbg.h>` file is included in `<iostream>` ?

Comment: I finally found where `<crtdbg.h>` is included in `<iostream>` :

Comment: I finally found where `<crtdbg.h>` is included in `<iostream>` : `iostream > isstream > osstream > ios > xlocnum > streambuf > xiosbase > xlocale > stdexcept > xstring > xmemory > xutility > crtdbg`.